# Rewrite JS callbacks to use promises

Tags: javascript, promise, callback

I have recently just come across JS promises, so I want to rewrite a lot of callbacks to use promises. Looking at examples seems very straight forward and easy, until I have to adapt it myself.

I have the following example below, that I want to rewrite to use promises.

```
getData = function (id, key, required, callback) {
  // do a lot of things
  let lParams = {
    tParams: { start: 0, Query: numQueries },
    callback: () =>  {
      if (!required)
        showGrid(id);
      if (callback)
        callback();
    }
  };
  //do some work...
  e = some condition
  if(e)
    e.load(tParams);
  else { 
    e.read(new data.Operation(tParams), tParams.callback);
  }
```

----------------- Example of where the function is used -------

The usage could even occur from another js file

```
report.execute = function (params) {
      // Do a lot of things...
      showMessage("Working on data ...");
      getData(curFormID, data.key, false
        , function () {
          workStat = 1;
          ppl.pageReady();
        });
    }
  });
};
```

----------------- My attempt so far to rewrite to use promises -----------------

```
getData = async (isoForm, nKey, onlyGet) => {
  
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     // do the things that are in the getData function above???
  })
}
```

How will I connect this with the `report.execute(...)`
Thanks in advance

Comment: what happens to `lParams` after you populate them in `getData`?

Comment: I added more info in lParams, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Can you provide code that is self-contained? Currently `tParams` is referenced, but not defined, same for `numQueries`, `showGrid`, `data`, `e.read`, ... It is hard to suggest anything when there are so many "magic" references in your code.

Comment: How could `e.read` work when you have just tested that  `e` is falsy?

Comment: if you want a comprehensive answer, you'll need to provide more context code. in your usage example, mutation in a callback `workStat = 1` is a red flag. callback and promises can do more than just synchronize _timing_ the code, they can also contain data.

Comment: "*do the things that are in the getData function above?*" - yes. And replace `callback` by `resolve`.

Comment: "*How will I connect this with the `report.execute(...)`?*" - in the `execute` function, you'll do `getData(curFormID, data.key, false).then(() => { workStat = 1; ppl.pageReady(); });` or `await getData(curFormID, data.key, false); workStat = 1; ppl.pageReady();`.